# Array is not displaying correct values

Tags: java

I am new to java,I have created array which accepts 8 values. It's working fine,also accepting values but it's not displaying correct output on console,please help me what the problem can be ??

Here's my code,

```
import java.util.*;


public class array2

{
    public static void main(String []args)

    {


        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);    
    int[] nums=new int[8];  

        for(int count=0;count<8;count++)

        {

            nums[count]=scan.nextInt();     

        }


        System.out.println(nums);


    }



}
```

Comment: What do you expect, What do you get and whats your input?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java

Comment: You may use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));` (`import java.util.Arrays` to do this)

If you just say `System.out.println(nums);`, it will only print the object reference to the array and not the actual array elements. This is because array objects do not override the `toString()` method, so they get printed using the [default `toString()` method from Object class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), which just prints the [class name]@[hashcode] of the object instance.

Comment: thanks alot,it just solved my problem,so nice of you for explaing also :D

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are printing the array object instead of elements

Use this

```
for(int i : nums){
   System.out.println(i);
}
```

- The `[` symbol in the output indicates that the object being printed
  is an array.
- Alternatively, you can do
  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));`. This gives `String` representation of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Printing an array like that is not possible in Java, you probably got something like "[I"...
Try looping:

```
for (int n=0; n<nums.length; ++n)
  System.out.println(nums[n]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Display array in a loop:

```
for(int count=0; count<8; count++)
{
   System.out.println(nums[count])
}
```

You are printing array reference, not their elements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Arrays.toString(int[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), to create string that will contain the expected from. Currently you are printing string representation of array itself.

Answer (score 0):

nums[count]=scan.nextInt() will only print the memory location of the array and not the array contents. To print the array contents you need to loop as you did when you insert them. I would try:

```
for(int count=0;count<8;count++){

    System.out.println(nums[count]);
 }
```

Hope that helps